# Using 'for loop' in Scilab, especially in an exercise (described below)

Tags: for-loop, scilab

I'm a food engineering MA student and I have to use Scilab. I am very beginner at Scilab and I have got this problem/excercise:

"Write a short program to input an integer n and to build the n by n matrix A with entries
ai,j = 2^ij! "

I have to use 'for loop' to solve this excercise, however I don't really understand how 'for loop' works in Scilab. Can somebody give me a right code using for loop?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us that you have put some effort in it and tried to solve it on your own. SO does not do your home work for you :)

Comment: Using a for loop in Scilab language to implement this would be using Scilab as a low level language, instead of a powerful user- and matrix-oriented language. And it would be slow.